# Async and asynchronous methods clarification?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, async-await, c#-5.0

AFAIK  - ( and I read a lot about it),  asynchronous methods (***not*** asynchronous delegates !) exists to solve the "thread is blocked" problem when dealing with **I/O operations** like : reading a file or downloading a file :

Richter shows it quite clearly here :

[image]

- `Task<T>` is not related to the i/o blocking issue. it is simply just like open a thread ( *plus extra efficiency  + functionality* ) - but it still causes a thread to consume cpu quanta etc.

And here is my question :

I've read (msdn) that :

> An **async** method provides a convenient way to do potentially
>   long-running work **without blocking the caller's thread**. The caller of
>   an async method can resume its work without waiting for the async
>   method to finish.

- Is it just like creating a `Task<t>` with `ContinueWith` ?
- Doesn't the terminology is confusing ? `asynchronous methods` are for `i/o` operations  (where there are **zero** threads waiting while i/o operation is made and no thread is dealing with it). **But**  to call a code (which use async) as:  `asynchronous methods` is a bit confusing. don't you think ? because I assume there is another thread  which is executing...(which is my first question actually).

**Where is the confusion from ?**

Because [**Albahari tend to emphasize**](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA927&lpg=PA927&dq=%22The%20problem%20just%20described%20might%20be%20insoluble%20if%20every%20thread%20needed%20to%20be%20busy%22&source=bl&ots=3uYZli808V&sig=eyDe6pdWBUnyacvqRzeTHYEPFD8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FpO8UYnTDITvsgbk44CAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20problem%20just%20described%20might%20be%20insoluble%20if%20every%20thread%20needed%20to%20be%20busy%22&f=false) what Asynchronous methods are for :

[image]

*p.s. I've read a few question here at SO regarding this topic , but found none which talks about the misclassification   that asynchronous methods are here to deal with io operations*

Comment: maybe you already seen this video,if not it might help a bit http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Task<T>` is not related to the I/O blocking issue. It is simply just like open a thread (plus extra efficiency and functionality) - but it still causes a thread to consume CPU quanta etc.

Not necessarily. Basically there are two kinds of `Task`s: one executes a synchronous piece of code and completes when that code finishes executing. This kind of `Task` blocks a `Thread` the whole time since it starts executing until it's completed (successfully or not).

But there is another kind of `Task`: one that completes when something happens. This kind of `Task` is what .Net 4.5 and C# 5.0 use heavily and it doesn't block a `Thread` (at least not directly). You can create such `Task` yourself by using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

(Another point is that a blocked thread doesn't consume any CPU, but that's not really relevant here.)

> Is it just like creating a `Task<t>` with `ContinueWith`?

Yes, `await t` is quite similar to `t.ContinueWith(rest of the method)`.

> Doesn't the terminology is confusing? Asynchronous methods are for I/O operations (where there are zero threads waiting while I/O operation is made and no thread is dealing with it). But to call a code (which use async) as: asynchronous methods is a bit confusing. Don't you think? Because I assume there is another thread which is executing.

I don't see the confusion. Classic asynchronous method (like `BeginRead()`; this is called “Asynchronous Programming Model” or APM) is a way of starting an operation and being notified when it completes (though a callback). Modern async method (like `ReadAsync()`; this is called “Task-based Asynchronous Pattern” or TAP) is also a way of starting an operation and being notified when it completes (using `await`).

In both cases, there can be some code that executes before the method returns (the code before the first `await` in the TAP case).

In both cases, the usual way of being notified about the result doesn't block any threads (callback for APM, `await` for TAP).

In both cases, you can use blocking wait if you want (immediately calling the `EndXxx()` method for APM, `Wait()` for TAP).

Both cases can be used to execute synchronous code on a background thread (`BeginInvoke()` on a delegate for APM, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` for TAP).

Again, I don't see the confusion, the two models seem very similar to me.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean _"two kinds of Task"_ ?  there is just `Task<t>` which is executed at another thread. ( and each thread get quanta).  I dont understnad what 2 tasks you're talking about.

Comment: @RoyiNamir There is just one type (`Task<T>`), but it can actually represent two different kinds of `Task`s. And the other kind of `Task`s doesn't use a `Thread`. Have you looked at `TaskCompletionSource`?

Comment: [yeah of course I know it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316613/real-life-scenarios-for-using-taskcompletionsourcet) But itss just a plugin to an arbitary function as a **shell of a task**. ( so i can use it as a task) but its final result is a task. (another usage is http://i.stack.imgur.com/hyAlG.jpg). and of course thanks for reply ( as always)

Comment: @RoyiNamir The point is, this kind of `Task` doesn't directly use a `Thread`. So it cam complete when a timer ticks or when an APM method callback is called or something like that. Which means it really is asynchronous.

Comment: Ok . Albahari put a lot of effort to emphesize that asynchrouns methods are used for io  only operations. please read the **second paragraph** http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA927&lpg=PA927&dq=%22The+problem+just+described+might+be+insoluble+if+every+thread+needed+to+be+busy%22&source=bl&ots=3uYZli808V&sig=eyDe6pdWBUnyacvqRzeTHYEPFD8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FpO8UYnTDITvsgbk44CAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20problem%20just%20described%20might%20be%20insoluble%20if%20every%20thread%20needed%20to%20be%20busy%22&f=false

Comment: @RoyiNamir I still don't understand the confusion. TAP can also be used to execute many concurrent I/O requests on just a few threads.

Comment: can you provide an example for _TAP can also be used to execute many concurrent I/O requests on just a few threads_ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know what you're expecting from me. If you for example have an ASP.NET application that uses `async` for some I/O and have lots of requests at the same time, that's exactly what will happen. Another example is when you start lots of asynchronous downloads in a loop and then use `await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)`.

Answer (score 3):

Async methods are not *just* for IO - they can be for anything - and yes, it's just another way of saying that the work of the method is executed in a separate thread. Any method where the calling thread offloads the work to a separate thread can be correctly called an "async" method. It is the same as `Task<T>` and `ContinueWith` -- `ContinueWith` is just another way of talking about a callback, really.

The word "asynchronous" simply means *"not at the same time"* - it can refer to any actions that happen independently of each other.