# xamarin android async task alertdialog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await, android-alertdialog

I work with visual studio 2015 and xamarin android
I have a little project with a button and a textview
On click on the button, I start a for(int=0 ...) method and try to get the content of some web page and place this content into the textview. this method is async

that works fine ...

Now, I would like on each loop (for) add an alert dialog and wait for the response of the user?
My problem is when I start the debugger the method for(..) starts download file for each loop and displays each loop the alert dialog ... WITHOUT wait for the response!

I'm new to task and I'm sure I'm not understood how to use or something else .
Any idea about how to wait for the response of the alert dialog.

here is it the code :

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = "";
    await CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
    FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text += "Control returned to startButton_Click.";
}
```

now the code of the async method:

```
async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };

    int max = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        // Create and start the tasks. As each task finishes, DisplayResults  
        // displays its length.
        Task<int> download1 = ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
        Task<int> download2 = ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx", client);
        Task<int> download3 = ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);

        // Await each task. 
        int length1 = await download1;
        int length2 = await download2;
        int length3 = await download3;

        // Display the total count for the downloaded websites.
        int total = length1 + length2 + length3;
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text += string.Format("\r\n\r\n Start {0} Tour for an total bytes returned:  {1}\r\n", i, total);

        //display alertDialog
        var x = await displayAlertDialogBox(i);
    }
}
```

and the last code the alert dialog

```
async Task<int> displayAlertDialogBox(int loop)
{
    int ret = 0;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
    dialog.SetTitle("ALERT DIALOG");
    dialog.SetMessage(string.Format("COUNT {0} ITEM {1}", loop, "content"));
    dialog.SetCancelable(true);
    dialog.SetButton("OK button", (z, ev) =>
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, string.Format("Ok button {0}", loop), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        ret = 99;
    });
    dialog.SetButton2("Cancel button", (z, ev) =>
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, string.Format("Cancel button {0}", loop), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        ret = 1;
    });

    //
    dialog.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
    dialog.Show();

    //
    return (ret > 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you need wait for the response of the user ?  You could do your logic in the dialog button click event.

Comment: Consider using a `TaskCompletionSource` so you can allow the flow to be awaited as desired.

Comment: Sorry for late, you could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701662/returning-a-true-false-value-from-a-funcobject-bool-implementation-with-an-an/45715249#45715249

Answer (score 1):

This extension method allows to show Android.AlertDialog asynchronous

```
    public static async Task<bool?> ShowAlertDialogAsync(this Context context,
        string title, string message,
        string positive = default,
        string negative = default,
        string neutral = default)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool?>();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).SetTitle(title).SetMessage(message)
            .SetPositiveButton(positive, (sender, args) => source.SetResult(true))
            .SetNegativeButton(negative, (sender, args) => source.SetResult(false))
            .SetNeutralButton(neutral, (sender, args) => source.SetResult(default))
            .Show();

        return await source.Task;
    }
```

For questions

```
    var result = await activity.ShowAlertDialogAsync
    (
        "Question", "Confirm the action?", "Yes", "No"
    );
    
    if (result is true) PerformAction();
```

For notices

```
    await activity.ShowAlertDialogAsync
    (
        "Notice", "Hey, you are so fine!", neutral: "Ok"
    );
```